# Dropwizard serving static html

Tags: java, angularjs, dropwizard

I'm currently building an application using dropwizard and angularjs. I have setup my AssetsBundle like so:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/", "index.html"));
```

My current issue is that I want multiple pages to serve my index.html page (main angularjs app page). Is there anyway I can define a set of url's to all serve this index.html file? If I create more asset bundles this will work however this is not how it should be done:

```
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/login", "index.html", "login"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/my-leagues", "index.html", "my-leagues"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/registering-leagues", "index.html", "registering-leagues"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/league-register/*", "index.html", "league-register"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/", "index.html", "home"));
```

My goal currently is to have the index.html page be served for /login, /my-leagues, /registering-leagues, /league-register/* (where * can be any number), and /. This hacky solution does not work for the "/league-register/*" asset as the asset bundle does not support wild cards.

Is there an easy way to specify certain endpoints to return my index.html file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, still not sure if this is the best solution though. I created a servlet that just serves my index.html file. Inside of my run function I have added:

```
    environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet(new ServletHolder(new BaseServlet()), "/login");
    environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet(new ServletHolder(new BaseServlet()), "/my-leagues");
    environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet(new ServletHolder(new BaseServlet()), "/registering-leagues");
    environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet(new ServletHolder(new BaseServlet()), "/league-register/*");
```

My BaseServlet looks like this:

```
public class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");

        view.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```